# Xml-Based Report Generator

Tags: c#, sql, xml, visual-studio, report

The software I am working with gathers data, processes it into an xml, and then sends that xml to be printed out in pdf format. Right now, I am using ActiveReports as my report builder for the pdf. However, I am unhappy with some things about active reports and am looking into other options. Is there any xml-based report generator out there that includes a "layout manager" or some kind of UI that allows easier building of reports? I would like to be able to somehow dynamically put these reports together based on what fields I choose on my WPF form, etc.

Comment: I might add that a lot of my issues with using ActiveReports come from when I want to reuse a report but remove pieces; I have to manually reformat the layout of all of the other controls on the page.

Answer (score 0):

take a look into [List&Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label), it has a lot of options available. there is a nice layout-manager but you can do a lot things programmatically too. just try it out, it has helped us a lot in the past